# Does Google Analytics track users with multiple languages?

Tags: google-analytics, multilingual

I'm assuming that when Google Analytics tracks a visitor's language it uses the Accept-language header from the request (most browser/OS combinations seem to populate it automatically).

My browser sends:

```
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,fr-CA;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
```

And yet I can't figure out how to get stats on what percentage of my visitors *can* speak a certain language even if it isn't their primary one (in my case I normally use English but I can use French).  Does any analytics program do this, or am I going to have to capture it in my logs and track it manually?

Comment: So it looks like about 3% of users send multiple languages in the Accept-language headers: http://euri.ca/2011/05/20/multiple-languages-in-accept-language-header/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics claims to track the ["preferred *language* [not *languages*] that visitors have configured on their computers."](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60127)

This implies that they strip info after the first semicolon in the Accept-Language header. It's hard to tell from their documentation whether or not this is the case for sure, but you could test it by creating a secret page, adding analytics code, visiting it ten times yourself, and seeing which languages were reported under Visitors>Languages.

[Competing services](http://imimpact.com/web-stats-alternatives-to-google-analytics/) appear to take the same approach, so your options appear to be limited to using [Google Analytics custom variables](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/quick-tip-the-power-of-google-analytics-custom-variables/) or [Woopra Custom Visitor Data](http://www.woopra.com/features/custom-visitor-data/) or a home-baked solution to manipulate and store the full Accept-Language header.

Comment: Ok, so I think what I'm going to do is add some custom variables "speaks french" "speaks german" and "speaks chinese" thanks!

Comment: Btw, there's a related post on StackOverflow [How do Google Analytics collect “user language” data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838214/how-do-google-analytics-collect-user-language-data), which contains a link to [Languages Report in Google Analytics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/02/12/languages-report-google-analytics/) which has a lot more information about how GA slices users up from the `Accept-Language:` header.